# django passing a dictionary to views.py and using it in another page

Tags: django

In professor_page.html, I have a dictionary (professorData) which contains the data I collect from this page and when navigate to student page, I want to pass this dictionary to the student page.
professor_page.html:

```
function navigateToStudentPage() {
            var csrfToken = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
            var data = {
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrfToken,
                'professorData': JSON.stringify(professorData), // Convert the dictionary to a JSON string
                'formData': $('#professor-form').serialize() // Include any other form data if needed
              };

            var studentPageUrl = '{% url 'student_page' %}' + '?' + data;
            $.ajax({
                url: '{% url 'student_page' %}',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                success: function(response) {
                    window.location.href = studentPageUrl; // Redirect to the student page URL
                }
            });
        }
```

views.py:

```
def student_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        professor_data = request.POST.get('professorData')
        professors = json.loads(professor_data)
        # Access the professor data as a dictionary
        for professor, time_slots in professors.items():
            print("POST")
            print(professor)
            print(time_slots)
    else:
        professor_data = request.GET.get('professorData')
        professors = json.loads(professor_data)
        # Access the professor data as a dictionary
        for professor, time_slots in professors.items():
            print("GET")
            print(professor)
            print(time_slots)


    context = {'professors': professors}
    return render(request, 'myapp/student_page.html', context)
```

The question is why is this dictionary not passing to the student page

I tried to print the data and seems like the student page using the data from GET request, and the GET portion of code does not get the dictionary.

Comment: It makes two requests: one with POST and one with GET: the AJAX one performs a POST and then visits the page through GET by setting the location.

Comment: Looks like you are sending a rendered page back to the front end, but you are not doing anything with it.  It's just sitting in your response variable.    Your JavaScript student_page_url is worthless here. To see what I mean do a console.log(response) in your success function